# How to validate google recaptcha when you have multiple widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I want to validate each recaptcha on its form submission.
i cant create callback using this `onload=onloadCallback` in recaptcha script. because my below script is in after lot of ajax calls.. and its giving me **ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: onloadCallback** error if i used the call back methods.

i want to validate each recaptcha with any different method except callback.

i also tried with this tutorial https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display but i am getting above error.

**Update:** 
I am using a form builder which  is generating a field for captcha..and there is lot of forms on a page..
When each form renders then i checked each form has captcha then generate a div to show captcha.

Que: How can i use onloadCallback when i am using directly Html tag to render captcha ?

This one could be the solution

```
grecaptcha.getResponse('html_element');
```

but when i put my id in this it is giving me error.

script:

```
$(formWrap).each(function(id, j) {
    $('#_form-render-wrap-form-' + id).formRender({
        dataType: 'json',
        formData: result.Form.form_data_json,
        onRender: function onRender() {
                $.getScript( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
                    $("div.fb-captcha captcha.google-recaptcha").html('<div id="html_element" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Len7RkUA"></div>');
                });
            }
        }
  });
```

Comment: you sure you dont have a `<script>` tag or script getting downloaded elsewhere on page with `onload` specified in URL, e.g `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback`. BTW, callback method name in recaptcha documentation website is `onloadCallback`, same as in your error. I could be you copied the code from documentation and its hanging somewhere on your page.

Comment: @codneto i updated my question.. your suggestion are welcome. can we make  a chat room on stackoverflow ?

Comment: Never used stackoverflow chat, so need to look into that, but first thing you need is use render=explicit for loading script. Then use explicit render() api to render the recaptcha widgets . `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit`. Then create a `window.onloadCallback` function which gets called when script is loaded. If you use jQuery to load script, omit the `onload=` param of script.